# Functional pattern matching in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, library

I recently read a really interesting [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156467/switch-pattern-matching-idea) on adding [functional pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) to C#. Here's a quick and dirty implementation using delegates and dictionaries.

Right now, I require that `Match` return an object of type `TReturn`. Is there any way I can easily extend my current implementation to be `void` (i.e. `Match` is not required to return anything) without significant code duplication? When I first tried this, I ended up essentially copying `Match` but omitting the second type parameter.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a switch on TIn. 
/// </summary>
public class Match<TIn, TReturn>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> funcs =
        new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    private Dictionary<TIn, TReturn> values =
        new Dictionary<TIn, TReturn>();

    private TReturn _else;

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a case, action pair
    /// </summary>
    public void Case<T>(Func<T, TReturn> func)
        where T : TIn
    {
        funcs[typeof(T)] = func;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a case, value pair
    /// </summary>
    public void Case(TIn x, TReturn value)
    {
        values[x] = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the default case value
    /// </summary>
    public void Else(TIn x, TReturn value)
    {
        _else = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evaluates the match on a query
    /// Returns an object of type TReturn 
    /// for first successful match
    /// </summary>
    public TReturn Eval<T>(T query) 
        where T : TIn 
    {
        TReturn value;
        if (values.TryGetValue(query, out value))
            return value;

        Delegate func;
        if (funcs.TryGetValue(query.GetType(), out func))
            return (TReturn)func.DynamicInvoke(query);

        return _else;
    }
}
```

And here's a simple test. One thing I was wondering: is it inefficient to declare a new `Match` inside the `Calculate` method?

```
class Program
{
    public static double Calculate(Expression exp)
    {
        var match = new Match<Expression, double>();
        match.Case<Num>((x) => x.Value);
        match.Case<Mul>((x) => Calculate(x.Left) * Calculate(x.Right));
        match.Case<Add>((x) => Calculate(x.Left) + Calculate(x.Right));
        return match.Eval(exp);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression tree = new Add(new Add(new Num(1), new Num(2)), new Mul(new Num(3), new Num(4)));
        double x = Calculate(tree) // = 15
    }
}

abstract class Expression
{
    public double Value;
}

abstract class BinaryExpression : Expression
{
    public Expression Left;
    public Expression Right;

    public BinaryExpression(Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        Left = left; Right = right;
    }
}

class Add : BinaryExpression
{
    public Add(Expression left, Expression right)
        : base(left, right)
    {
    }
}

class Mul : BinaryExpression
{
    public Mul(Expression left, Expression right)
        : base(left, right)
    {
    }
}

class Num : Expression
{
    public Num(double x)
    {
        Value = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning, shameless self promotion: If you are interested in examining other existing pattern matching solutions, you may wish to read up on https://github.com/DavidArno/SuccincT/wiki/PatternMatching.

Comment: There's a small bug in the definition of `Else`; it should only take a `TReturn`, not a `TIn`. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

In your `Match` class, I would mark the two private dictionaries as `readonly` to signify intent and keep them from being assigned to accidentally anywhere else:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> funcs =
    new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

private readonly Dictionary<TIn, TReturn> values =
    new Dictionary<TIn, TReturn>();
```

Secondly, I'd design to interfaces and make them `IDictionaries` as good OO practice:

```
private readonly IDictionary<Type, Delegate> funcs =
    new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

private readonly IDictionary<TIn, TReturn> values =
    new Dictionary<TIn, TReturn>();
```

In your example classes, you should forego `public` member data and use properties accessing backing fields (also marked `readonly`):

```
abstract class Expression
{
    private readonly double _Value;

    protected Expression(double value)
    {
        this._Value = value;
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Value;
        }
    }
}

abstract class BinaryExpression : Expression
{
    private readonly Expression _Left;

    private readonly Expression _Right;

    public BinaryExpression(Expression left, Expression right) : base(default(double))
    {
        this._Left = left;
        this._Right = right;
    }

    public Expression Left
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Left;
        }
    }

    public Expression Right
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Right;
        }
    }
}

class Add : BinaryExpression
{
    public Add(Expression left, Expression right) : base(left, right)
    {
    }
}

class Mul : BinaryExpression
{
    public Mul(Expression left, Expression right) : base(left, right)
    {
    }
}

class Num : Expression
{
    public Num(double x) : base(x)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I usually make my fields `public readonly`. Thanks for the suggestions!